# How to write a T-SQL Having query?

Tags: having, sql-server-2008

I am using SSMS 2008 and am trying to write a TSQL statement to return only records with multiple "intake_dt" values per "people_id".  But this query below doesn't seem to be working.  How do I rewrite this?

```
SELECT el.people_id, el.actual_date
INTO #READMISSIONS
from event_log_rv el
 join enrollment_view en on en.event_log_id = el.event_log_id
 join (select actual_date from event_log_rv where actual_date is not null group by actual_date having count(*) > 1) t on t.actual_date = el.actual_date
where el.actual_date is not null 
group by el.people_id, el.actual_date
```

I am not getting any errors, but the output is not displaying just one record / person.  All I want is one record per person with the latest actual_date.

Comment: *But this query below doesn't seem to be working*. In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? If so, please post your error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the result you want?

```
    SELECT el.people_id,
    Max(el.actual_date) Max_Actual_Date
INTO #READMISSIONS
FROM event_log_rv el
INNER JOIN enrollment_view en
    ON en.event_log_id = el.event_log_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT actual_date
    FROM event_log_rv
    WHERE actual_date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY actual_date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t
    ON t.actual_date = el.actual_date
GROUP BY el.people_id,
```